# Count the number of water pixels in an image collection (Landsat 5)

Tags: google-earth-engine, pixel, count, reducers

I'm trying to count the number of water pixels across a Landsat 5 image collection. I have a script which I believe is successful in identifying the water pixels in each image and spiting a chart with each pixel identified (see below). I'd like to sum the number of mndwi pixels in the collection, but every time I try different reducers it only gives me a band, when I'd like a value. What do I need to do?

Here is the relevant part of my script:

````
//modNDWI (modified Normalized Difference Water Index)
//MNDWI = (GREEN − SWIR)/(GREEN + SWIR)
var mndwi = function(image) {
  var fun_mndwi = ee.Image(0).expression(
    '((B2 - B5) / (B2 + B5))', {
      'B2': image.select('B2'),
      'B5': image.select('B5'),
    });
  return image.addBands(fun_mndwi.rename('mndwi'));
};

////////////////////////////////

// Add a Function which removes pixels
var h2opixel = function(image) {
var maskpixel = image.select('mndwi').gt(-0.1);
  return image.mask(maskpixel);
};

////Map function over image collection
var collection_mndwi = lsat5masked.map(mndwi)
  .select('mndwi');//now only 1 banded images
Map.addLayer(collection_mndwi, mndwiParams,'collection_mndwi');//applied index
var FinalDataset = collection_mndwi.map(h2opixel);//filtered by -0.1
Map.addLayer(FinalDataset,mndwiParams,'final datset');

print(FinalDataset);
///////////////////////

///This is what won't work they way I'd like:

//count total number of pixels 
var count3 = FinalDataset.reduce({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count()
  });
print(count3);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the sum of some pixels in a region of an image you need to use `.reduceRegion()`. [See here for the documentation.](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_reduce_region)

So in your case if you want to calculate the number of water pixels for each Image in the Collection you would map over the collection and apply `.reduceRegion()` to each image.

```
//count total number of pixels 
var water_sums = FinalDataset.map(function(image){
  var reduced = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: geometry, // NEEDS TO BE CREATED
    scale: 30
  })
  return ee.Feature(null, reduced)
})
```